# Encrypt in C# Decrypt AES CBC 256

Tags: c#, c++, encryption, aes

I want encrypt in C# and decrypt in c++ but I have some Encoding problem :

example variables  :

Key : g*OtIPaL*ver—vS5UAnJbPqsDZSf,yJ1
IVString : g*OtIPaL*ver—vS5

my c# code :

```
public static string EncryptString(string message, string KeyString, string IVString)
    {
        byte[] Key = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(KeyString.Substring(0,32));
        byte[] IV = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(IVString);

        string encrypted = null;
        RijndaelManaged rj = new RijndaelManaged();
        rj.Key = Key;
        rj.IV = IV;
        rj.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        rj.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        try
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, rj.CreateEncryptor(Key, IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(cs))
                {
                    sw.Write(message);
                    sw.Close();
                }
                cs.Close();
            }
            byte[] encoded = ms.ToArray();
            encrypted = Convert.ToBase64String(encoded);

            ms.Close();
        }
        catch (CryptographicException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("A Cryptographic error occurred: {0}", e.Message);
            return null;
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("A file error occurred: {0}", e.Message);
            return null;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: {0}", e.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            rj.Clear();
        }
        return encrypted;
    }
```

When I try encrypt and my Key have some not ASCII char - count of bytes is more than lenght of string .

How Encoding I shound use ? In C++ I use EVP (default padding is PKCS7) .

```
static string decryptEX(string KS, string ctext)
{
EVP_CIPHER_CTX* ctx;
ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
string IV = KS.substr(0, 16);
int rc = EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), NULL, (byte*)&KS[0], (byte*)&IV[0]);
std::string rtext;
rtext.resize(ctext.size());

int out_len1 = (int)rtext.size();
rc = EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, (byte*)&rtext[0], &out_len1, (const byte*)&ctext[0], (int)ctext.size());


int out_len2 = (int)rtext.size() - out_len1;
rc = EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(ctx, (byte*)&rtext[0] + out_len1, &out_len2);
try
{
    rtext.resize(out_len1 + out_len2);
}
catch (exception e)
{

}
return rtext;
```

}

Comment: Strings tend to not be very happy carrying embedded null values, but 0x00 bytes can appear in both keys and IVs, so if you need a textual representation you should generally use Base64.  You also shouldn't have a fixed IV for a key, because that causes the same message to encrypt the same way; and it really really shouldn't share bytes (intentionally) with the key, since the IV is usually transmitted with the message.

Answer (score 1):

Your call to

```
byte[] Key = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(KeyString.Substring(0,32));
```

fails because there are not 32 *characters* in that string. Yes, there would be 32 bytes if the string is encoded as UTF8. But Substring takes a count of characters.

Changing that line to

```
byte[] Key = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(KeyString);
```

gives a 32-byte long key.

Since you can't count on getting proper input for the KeyString, you could validate *after* this point that your key length is long enough.

```
byte[] Key = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(KeyString);
if (Key.Length < 32)
   throw new KeyLengthException("some useful info as to why this was thrown"); // or some other appropriate Exception type you create or resuse.
```

If I'm correct in assuming which key, IV, and block sizes you require, this should do what you need:

```
    public static string EncryptString(string message, string KeyString, string IVString)
    {
        byte[] Key = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(KeyString).Take(32).ToArray();
        if (Key.Length < 32)
            throw new Exception("KeyString not at least 32 bytes.");
        byte[] IV = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(IVString).Take(16).ToArray();
        if (Key.Length < 32)
            throw new Exception("IVString not at least 16 bytes.");
        string encrypted = null;
        RijndaelManaged rj = new RijndaelManaged();
        rj.KeySize = 128;
        rj.BlockSize = 128;
        rj.Key = Key;
        rj.IV = IV;
        rj.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        rj.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        try
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, rj.CreateEncryptor(Key, IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(cs))
                {
                    sw.Write(message);
                    sw.Close();
                }
                cs.Close();
            }
            byte[] encoded = ms.ToArray();
            encrypted = Convert.ToBase64String(encoded);

            ms.Close();
        }
        catch (CryptographicException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("A Cryptographic error occurred: {0}", e.Message);
            return null;
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("A file error occurred: {0}", e.Message);
            return null;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: {0}", e.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            rj.Clear();
        }
        return encrypted;
    }
```

Comment: Except a) Use Aes instead of Rijndael, b) Use Aes.Create() instead of picking your implementation, c) setting both KeySize and Key is redundant, d) once you switch to Aes 128 is the only legal BlockSize, e) the Aes (or Rijndael) object is IDisposable, so instead of try/finally{Clear()} it could just be in a using statement.

Comment: @bartonjs: thank you. all very good points. if it weren't "how do I fix this error", this would be an excellent candidate for codereview.stackexchange